# D3 expand force network by clicks - not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have the following simple graph to visualize:

[sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzLBu.png)

First, only 'n1' is shown connecting to its neighbor 'n2'

Second, after 'n2' is clicked, the network expands by adding two edges 'n2'->'n3' and 'n2'->'n4'

Third, after 'n3' is clicked, the network expands by adding two edges 'n3'->'n1' and 'n3'->'n5'.

To do so, i thought i could create an array of nodes that are visible. By clicking a node, this node name will be added into the array. And then in the tick() function the visible nodes in that array will be used to set up the network.

But when I do so with the following code:

```
// return currently visible nodes as the source nodes
// e.g. called by
// var visible_seeds = seeding(nodes);
//
function seeding(nodes){
    var visible = [];
    nodes.forEach(function(n){
        if(n.name=='n1')
        visible.push(n);
    });
    return visible;
}
```

The above function is then called as following:

```
var visible_seeds = seeding(nodes);

var force = d3.layout.force()
.nodes(d3.values(visible_seeds))
.links(links)
.size([width, height])
.linkDistance(60)
.charge(-300)
.on("tick", tick)
.start();
```

It gives the error

> index.html TypeError:'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'nodes.forEach(function(n){...')

What is the correct way to achieve my goal? Thank you out there!!!

p.s. I am absolutely new to D3 and javascript.

The data read in by D3 are from a csv file:

```
source,target,value
n1,n2,1.0
n2,n3,1.0
n2,n4,1.0
n3,n1,1.0
n3,n5,1.0
```

My code is based on the example at:
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5155181

**Added - source code** - the issue happens in the function seeding()

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style>

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

path.link.twofive {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

path.link.fivezero {
  opacity: 0.50;
}

path.link.sevenfive {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

path.link.onezerozero {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  fill: #000;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script>


// get the data
d3.csv("force.csv", function(error, links) {

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, vis:0});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, vis:0});
    link.value = +link.value;
});

//nodes["n1"] = {name:"n1", vis:1};
var vis = ['n1'];

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

function seeding(){
 var visible = [];
 nodes.forEach(function(n){
     if(n.name=='n1')
        visible.push(n);
 });
 return visible;
}

var visible_seeds = seeding();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(visible_seeds))
    //.nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

// Set the range
var  v = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 100]);

// Scale the range of the data
v.domain([0, d3.max(links, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

// asign a type per value to encode opacity
links.forEach(function(link) {
    if (v(link.value) <= 25) {
        link.type = "twofive";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 50 && v(link.value) > 25) {
        link.type = "fivezero";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 75 && v(link.value) > 50) {
        link.type = "sevenfive";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 100 && v(link.value) > 75) {
        link.type = "onezerozero";
    }
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

// add the links and the arrows
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

// define the nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click)
    .on("dblclick", dblclick)
    .call(force.drag);

// add the nodes
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5);

// add the text 
node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// add the curvy lines
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + 
            d.source.x + "," + 
            d.source.y + "A" + 
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
            d.target.x + "," + 
            d.target.y;
    });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

// action to take on mouse click
function click() {
    d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", 22)
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke", "lightsteelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", ".5px")
        .style("font", "20px sans-serif");
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 16)
        .style("fill", "lightsteelblue");
}

// action to take on mouse double click
function dblclick() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 6)
        .style("fill", "#ccc");
    d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", 12)
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("font", "10px sans-serif");
}

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `TypeError:'undefined' is not a function` means that nodes is **not** a JavaScript array.  If it's a `d3` selection try `nodes.each(function...)`, otherwise you need to show us more code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The code is added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, the source of your error is because `nodes` is a JavaScript object (not an array), it has no `forEach` method.

Second, I'm not sure where you are going with your approach.  You start the force layout with one node, then what?  On click you append the other nodes?  How you going to handle the links?

Intead, I'd suggest just toggling the visibility of the nodes and links on click.  Here's a quick implementation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<style>

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

path.link.twofive {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

path.link.fivezero {
  opacity: 0.50;
}

path.link.sevenfive {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

path.link.onezerozero {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

circle {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  fill: #000;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script>


// get the data
//d3.csv("force.csv", function(error, links) {

var links = [{"source":"n1","target":"n2","value":"1.0"},{"source":"n2","target":"n3","value":"1.0"},{"source":"n2","target":"n4","value":"1.0"},{"source":"n3","target":"n1","value":"1.0"},{"source":"n3","target":"n5","value":"1.0 "}];

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source, vis:0});
    link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target, vis:0});
    link.value = +link.value;
});

//nodes["n1"] = {name:"n1", vis:1};
var vis = ['n1'];

var width = 300,
    height = 300;

for (key in nodes){
  var node = nodes[key];
  node.visible = (node.name === 'n1');
}

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(60)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

// Set the range
var  v = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 100]);

// Scale the range of the data
v.domain([0, d3.max(links, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

// asign a type per value to encode opacity
links.forEach(function(link) {
    if (v(link.value) <= 25) {
        link.type = "twofive";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 50 && v(link.value) > 25) {
        link.type = "fivezero";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 75 && v(link.value) > 50) {
        link.type = "sevenfive";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 100 && v(link.value) > 75) {
        link.type = "onezerozero";
    }
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
  .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

// add the links and the arrows
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
  .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "link " + d.type; })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .style("opacity", function(d){
      return d.target.visible && d.source.visible ? 1 : 0;
    })

// define the nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .style("opacity", function(d){
      return d.visible ? 1 : 0;
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);

// add the nodes
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5);

// add the text 
node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// add the curvy lines
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + 
            d.source.x + "," + 
            d.source.y + "A" + 
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
            d.target.x + "," + 
            d.target.y;
    });

    node
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}

// action to take on mouse click
function click(d0) {
  links.forEach(function(d1){
    console.log(d0, d1.source)
    if (d1.source === d0) {
      d1.target.visible = !d1.target.visible;
    }
  });
  node.style("opacity", function(d){
    return d.visible ? 1 : 0;
  });
  path.style("opacity", function(d){
    return d.target.visible && d.source.visible ? 1 : 0;
  });
}

//});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, you almost solved it. What I want is to incremental display (by expanding) the graph. Imagine that there are not just 5 but 5000 nodes - computing them all might be slow, so I want to start with one node. By clicking it, we will load its neighboring nodes and of course the links between them. Clicking one of the neighboring nodes will add new neighboring nodes and edges, so on and so forth.